# Vue JS slots[name$1].every is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to add a prototype `isEmpty` for `Object` this way:

```
Object.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
  for (var key in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

And this leads to the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: slots[name$1].every is not a function
```

I am using `Vue.js` 2.6.

What is the nature of this error and what is the best way to add `isEmpty` or other methods to `Object`? I tested the same for `Array` and `String`, they work well. The problem is with `Object` only.

Comment: How and in which part of the code are you adding `isEmpty` to the prototype? I've just tried adding it myself to a project of mine that uses `Vue.js 2.6.10` and I couldn't reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue after adding a new function to the Object.prototype object and opened an issiue on github:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/10839

Comment: This is not an answer, it's just a comment